# sending images into the divs randomly

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a html5 project and i also use jquery.  This project is a sorting game. I want to make a shuffle for these images.  For example i have 3 cards, when i start the game,  i have the cards this order 1-2-3.  When i achieved to sort this order then i want to make order for example 2-3-1.  Is there any solution to make this ?

```
<div id="source1" class="block">1</div> 
<div id="source2" class="block">2</div>
<div id="source3" class="block">3</div>
<br>
<div id="dest1" class="dest">1</div>
<div id="dest2" class="dest">2</div>
<div id="dest3" class="dest">3</div>
```

This is an example, i want to send images into these divs and i also make the div id according to this images number.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do like this:

- get all the images
- shuffle the images (list, e.g. array)
- loop divs, set the image to the n-th image in the list (is already shuffled).
- set the id foreach div you are looping according to the n-th image

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

On [AR-labs.org](http://ar-labs.org/), we wanted to shuffle our images to have a random order. In order to archive this, we collected all images (using a shared class), looped through all elements and replaced it's content randomly with any of the containers contents (it could also replace itself).

Our code:

```
var persons = document.getElementsByClassName("person");
var personNum = persons.length;
for( var i = 0; i < personNum; i++ ){
    var b = Math.floor( Math.random() * personNum );
    persons[i].outerHTML = [persons[b].outerHTML, persons[b].outerHTML = persons[i].outerHTML][0];
}
```

It's pretty basic (not the most beautiful code), but it works.

When you want to use jQuery, just replace the DOM accesses with the corresponding jQuery functions.